# When installing the MongoDB library in PHP, how can I avoid this error about a missing extension?

Tags: php, mongodb

I ran the following command to install PHP library for MongoDB:

> `composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"`

But I am getting the following error, I have already installed mongo.dll and mongodb.dll extensions in WAMP server:

> `mongodb/mongodb 1.1.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs